# Jquery Mobile Event For A Specific Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have events that fire for multiple different pages in my application. I want to add all my scripts to my main my home page. How do I change the following event to only fire on a page with a specific id? So I can put all my page events for all my pages in one script and the events will fire only when the proper page is in the DOM.

Sample page event..
    $(document).bind('pageinit')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're really looking for... But yes, you can apply specific events to a given page by referencing its ID.

For example:

```
$( '#your_id_page' ).live( 'pagebeforecreate',function(event){
    alert( 'This page was just inserted into the dom!' );
});
```

You may check the event section of the online doc for more information: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html